# Domain admin can monitor all keystrokes. How can I prove that my computer is being targeted?

Tags: windows-10, domain-admin

I recently found out that my coworker who is domain admin in a large organization told me that he can monitor all keystrokes of any PCs in the domain he'd like and even he can look at any screen to see what user is up to.

Later I found out that he even check what I have in my computer without knowing my password in joking way...

I wanna take this issue to the management but before I do that I have to have a proof. All I remember is he claimed that he doesn't even exe file to accomplish that... What is his secret? How can I prove that he hijacks' computer?

Comment: First of all, do you know that he can do what he claims? Have you seen any evidence for it? Secondly, even if he can, how do you know he isn't permitted to do so?

Comment: Likely your coworker is just trying to antagonize you, and reporting it to management will just make you look silly, unless you are sure something improper has been done.

Comment: Everything you mention are normal functions for all kinds of endpoint management and security applications. We can only guess what he's doing. And not knowing that, we can't guess how to detect when you are under active monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

If he is domain admin, he can run anything he wants on any computer he wants. He has the power to do that.

And yes, he can check what you have on your computer without needing your password, as long as you don't have Bitlocker activated and didn't unlock the drive. Because as soon as you unlock the drive, he can see what is there if he wants to.

It's technically possible to do everything he told you, but I don't believe he is allowed to do that. There are privacy laws to protect you against him, corporate rules, and so on. If he is misusing his powers to spy on his coworkers, it will not end well.

> I wanna take this issue to the management but before I do that I have to have a proof.

You can talk to management you suspect someone with Domain Admin powers is messing up with your computer, and give anything you have to suspect that. They will probably get your computer, inspect all activity on it, and look at Active Directory logs for remote tasks executed on your computer. If they do find something, your coworker will be identified on the logs. If they don't find anything, your coworker was bluffing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to view your screen or log your keystrokes remotely, a software program to intercept them has to be running locally and transmitting the data. He cannot be intercepting them "without running an .exe" unless it's in interpreted program (ie python) or a hardware keylogger (<- in which case he would still be transferring the data to his servers with a program).

It may be possible for you to find evidence of keylogging or screen recording by checking Running Processes in Windows (this might blocked for you, depending on how stringent your group policy is). I'd also recommend viewing `C:\Program Files (x86)\` for any suspicious looking executables if you want to know what program exactly he is using to track you.

He may very well be within his responsibilities as a domain admin to access your keystrokes or screen, so taking this up with management is probably not a good idea, especially if you have no proof, and unless you know you are entitled to privacy (if you are using a company computer, they control it and you can't really complain).